# Comment edit cutoff time for moderators

Tags: support, moderators

Do moderators have additional privileges to edit comments after the usual 5 minute cutoff?

I ask because in the following question:

[Double Slit Experiment: How do scientists ensure that there's only one photon?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76162/double-slit-experiment-how-do-scientists-ensure-that-theres-only-one-photon#comment158548_76162)

I could have sworn that Qmechanic's original comment was "possible duplicate," which is why I had responded that I didn't think it was a duplicate.  This makes my response comment look rather silly, but I'm mainly curious because it's bothering me that my memory is failing.

Comment: Also, note the little pencil icon next to Qmechanic's comment. When a comment is edited (by anyone, not necessarily mod edits), that will show up.

Answer (score 11):

*Yes,* moderators can edit comments after the usual 5 minute window has ended, even comments by other users.

In the present case, there is a pencil icon behind my comment, so I did edit something, I might have written *possible duplicate* first, I don't remember now, but I'm pretty sure I changed it to *related* within 5 minutes. Your reply comment is only 2 minutes after mine. Moreover, a comment edit is not instantly updated on another user's screen unless he manually refreshes/reloads the page, so it is entirely plausible that we have unintentionally overlapped in our comments. Later I noticed a red notification button in the upper left corner of my brouwser (caused by the *@Qmechanic* in your reply comment), but I did not change anything because of the notification.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. We can edit all comments without a time limit. This is mainly supposed to be used for editing profanities (or other things) out of an otherwise useful comment. There's no special exception in the software to prevent moderators from editing their *own* comments after the 5 minute window, and it's not particularly necessary.

While it usually isn't intentional, we do tend to overshoot the 5 minute limit at times since we get no notification about it.